# How to concat INTs with separator in ClickHouse

Tags: sql, clickhouse

How is it possible to concat INT lines in CLickHouse with separator ',' ?
For example I make a request

```
SELECT ApplicationID , CampaignID  
from distributed.advertisers 
where AdvertiserID=994 and CampaignID in(318728,318422)
and ActionDate BETWEEN '2021-03-01' and '2021-05-01'
```

and get in result following:

[image]

My goal is to get following:

[image]

How should I change my request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```sql
SELECT
    arrayStringConcat(arrayMap(x -> toString(x), groupArray(ApplicationId)), ',') AS ApplicationId,
    CampaignID
FROM 
(
    /* emulate the test dataset */
    SELECT
        data.1 AS ApplicationId,
        data.2 AS CampaignID
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT arrayJoin([(1, 11), (2, 11), (10, 12), (11, 12)]) AS data
    )
)
GROUP BY CampaignID

/*
┌─ApplicationId─┬─CampaignID─┐
│ 1,2           │         11 │
│ 10,11         │         12 │
└───────────────┴────────────┘
*/
```

Comment: Привет, Владимир, спасибо большое!